# how can I dynamically resize an html textbox to avoid overflowing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I would like to know how to resize a textbox to prevent text nearby it from overflowing.
I have 3 elements in a row, a label, a text box, and a button. the label however, can have words of varying lengths. if the word is too long it will move the text input too far to the side and the button will overflow onto the next line. to preserve the style of the page, I would prefer that the button stays on the same line as the other 2 elements.
I am trying to get the text box to shrink only as much as necessary to allow room for the other elements.
can I do this with JQuery?

Edit: here's the JFiddle thing:
http://jsfiddle.net/425ve/2/
and here's the main code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
background-color:#000000;
color:#cccccc;
}
#chatbox{
width:100%;
height:85%;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#000000;
overflow:auto;
}
#mainchat{
width:82%;
float:left;
margin:0;
}
#sidebar{
float:left;
height:97%;
width:17%;
border-style:dashed;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#AAAAAA;
border-right:0;
border-top:0;
border-bottom:0;
overflow:auto;
}
#topbar{
border-style:dashed;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#AAAAAA;
 border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  float:left;
  width:82%;
}
a{
color:#cccccc;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
color:#CCCCEE;
background-color:111122;
}
#topbarname{
float:right;
}
#message{
width: 90%;
background-color:#000000;
border-color:#CCCCCC;
border-style:solid;
border-width: 1px;
color:CCCCCC;
}
#submitbutton{
background-color:#000000;
border-color:#CCCCCC;
border-style:solid;
border-width: 1px;
color:#CCCCCC;
}
</style>
<script>
function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
} 

function doSomething() {
    var myCookie = getCookie("IceID");

    if (myCookie == null) {
        window.location="login.php"
    }
    else {
        // do cookie exists stuff
    }
}
doSomething();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="topbar">
| Information | Logs | characters | Profile | Private logs | Messages | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> |
</div>
<div id="mainchat">
<div id="chatbox">
<?php
include("getpost.php");
//improve this with AJAX!
?>
</div>
<div id="input">
<form id="inputchat">
<b id="name">
<?php
echo $_COOKIE['IceID'];
?>
</b>
<input type="text" name="message" id="message"></input>
<input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="say"></input>
</form>
</div>
<div id="utools">
</div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="title">
A
</div>
<div id="list">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:to clarify, the name doesn't actively change while the page is being used(only right before being displayed), but it will be different depending on who loads the page. their username fits into that label.

Comment: Can you provide your code, of even better, create a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net').

Comment: most of the time you just need to add overflow:auto; in the containers css.

Comment: Depending on your setup, you could make the label `inline-block` and give it a max width.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey there is a part that redirects if a cookie isn't found; I think I've commented it out now.

Comment: @ZCoder, Yes, it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery. jQuery could make it much simpler though. I prefer vanilla.

```
var left = document.getElementById('name')
var resizable = document.getElementById('message')
var right = document.getElementById('submitbutton')
realign()
window.addEventListener('resize', realign)
function realign() {
    resizable.style.width = '0'
    var extraWidth = getWidth(resizable) // Measure the border and padding on it's own.
    resizable.style.width = getWidth(resizable.parentNode) - getWidth(left) - getWidth(right)
    function getWidth(element) { // Superior to offsetWidth because it measures fractions of a pixel which is even more relevant when using the browser zoom feature.
        var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect() // A accurate way to measure location on the screen.
        return rect.right - rec.left // The accurate width.
    }
}
```

The only adjustment you need would be to fix my typo(s) if I made any and then if you want to support older versions of IE, you need to use the alternative to addEventListener, Google it.

Comment: Firefox says: "TypeError: resizable is null"

Comment: resizable is null because there is no element with the ID message *at the time the script did run*. If you move the <script to be after the </form, that will solve the error.